# SBCL Delete Key on Mac Giving ^?

Tags: lisp

I am using SBCL Lisp on a Mac Pro Mavericks. When I run the sbcl command and drop into the interpreter the delete key prints ^? instead of deleting the last character.

Does anyone have a remedy for this issue?

Comment: Does the same behaviour happen when you're running `cat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to terminal preferences (<kbd>command-,</kbd>), `settings` --> `advanced`; then check the option `Delete sends Control-H`.

Comment: Tried that earlier, but doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: @ZenBalance: does it change things for `cat`?

Comment: what does `cat` refer to?

Comment: `cat` is a standard unix command (`man` and google are your friends); type `cat` at the command prompt in the terminal, type letters, hit `delete` before and after my suggested changes, report the observations in your question as suggested by Chris.

Comment: Got it! Working now. Didn't realize that another setting I had in my .bashrc which I was trying to use to fix the problem was messing up your solution.